Snippet code to hide a third part plugin that is showing his alert on Wordpress site health
a plugin is showing an alert on the Wordpress site health that is not really a security or a performance issue. I want to hide that message. The developer is currently never helping about this or a solution seems will not come soon.
There is a snippet code for telling Wordpress to exclude a plugin from being showed in the Wordpress site health tool?
I found guide for a plugin developer who want add his plugin to the site health but I never find how a snippet can remove a plugin that insert into site health without allowing the admin to turn off this notification.
Thank you!
I tried to find a solution with the plugin developer but no solution found. I try a Internet search but I never found a solution.
